# SQLAlchemy - Accounting for the None Case in a nested OR Relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a very simple table. (nonsense data is loaded right now)

[image]

My Goal - Given a Date, retrieve the current terms in session. (date >= term begin <= term end)

Doing this was fine.

```
    query = Session.query(schema.Term).\
        filter(and_(schema.Term.term_begin <= form.year.data,
                    (schema.Term.term_end >= form.year.data ))
```

However, when I try to account for the case that the term is still in session **IE** `term_end is None`, it does not retrieve the 3rd row. Inputting `2016-03-10` should retrieve all 3 records.

I am trying with this query.

```
    query = Session.query(schema.Term).\
        filter(and_(schema.Term.term_begin <= form.year.data,
                    or_(schema.Term.term_end >= form.year.data, schema.Term.term_end is None)))
```

But that returns the same query as the above.
2016-03-10

```
SELECT terms.id AS terms_id, terms.term_begin AS terms_term_begin, ter
ms.term_end AS terms_term_end, terms.term_served AS terms_term_served, terms.off
ice_id AS terms_office_id, terms.person_id AS terms_person_id, terms.state_id AS
 terms_state_id, terms.removal_reason_id AS terms_removal_reason_id
FROM terms
WHERE terms.term_begin <= :term_begin_1 AND terms.term_end >= :term_end_1
```

The word `or` isnt even included in the query. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '== None' instead of 'is None'

```
conn.query(Identifier.Key)\
    .filter(and_(Identifier.DatetimeStart <= datetime.datetime.now(),
        or_(Identifier.DatetimeEnd <= datetime.datetime.now(), Identifier.DatetimeEnd == None)))\
    .all()

SELECT identifier.identifier_id AS identifier_identifier_id 
    FROM identifier 
    WHERE identifier.datetime_start <= ? AND (identifier.datetime_end <= ? OR identifier.datetime_end IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, I can't believe I forgot that!